# Data Report filled at runtime shows the same record instead of every different record

Tags: mysql, vb6, runtime, report

I query a MySql table with 5 different records.
Then I fill a VB6 Data Report.
I have 5 records in the table with fields Name and Surname, problem is the report shows
5 same names instead of five different names.

The 5 same names all belong to the last record fetched from the database, here is the code to fill the Data Report label at runtime:

```
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset       'Creates record set
    strSQL = "select * from person"
     rs.Open strSQL, cn, strDBCursorType, strDBLockType, strDBOptions

If rs.EOF Then
   GoTo ExitSub
Else
    For B = 1 To rs.RecordCount
   'MsgBox (rs!Name + " " + rs!Surname)
    rptRuntime.Sections("Section1").Controls("lblName").Caption = rs!Name
   rs.MoveNext
    Next B
End If
    rptRuntime.Show
```

The label that is being filled is placed in the Detail section, named "Section1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to bind to the Recordset or a custom data source object.  Procedural code isn't required with DataReports.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code

```
For B = 1 To rs.RecordCount
'MsgBox (rs!Name + " " + rs!Surname)
rptRuntime.Sections("Section1").Controls("lblName").Caption = rs!Name
    rs.MoveNext
Next B
```

Is going to set rs!Name 5 times in a row, ending up with `rptRuntime.Sections("Section1").Controls("lblName").Caption` containing the last change. ALL 5 changes happened before the report is even displayed using

```
rptRuntime.Show
```

It goes without saying that you will have a (repeated report) section that has a fixed caption, showing the same caption in each repeat.

Comment: Is it possible to use an array of label controls, it's an idea but I wouldn't know how to add an array of label controls to the report at runtime...

Comment: Ok, I used textboxes instead of labels, then I could choose a field.